# How to clear any partitioning on an USB flash device on Win7 without admin rights?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, format

I am in a bit of a bind. I need to use my USB device to create a live-usb in order to boot into either my Windows7 partition. However, I do not have access to a computer with admin rights in order to use the Disk Manager (diskpart) utility. The USB device apparently has partitions that I need to erase because I currently only have access to about 31MB of storage space.

What are my options? Are there any partitioning utilities that I may use that do not require installation or admin rights? I only need access to a mounted USB flash device, not the system's partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *Disk Management Console* (Right click on Computer → Manage).

But as far as I know, you can't have that level of access on a device *without* admin rights. By the way, I suggest you use a proper tool like **gparted** or similar; it will really come in handy if you do this regularly.

Comment: Absolutely, but I have a sort of chicken-and-egg problem here. I need a bootable drive before I can regain access to the computer, yet I can't create one without having said access.

Comment: You can burn a dvd with a bootable image (gparted has its own bootable image), and you don't need admin privileges to burn a dvd.